# Shouldn't Gdiplus::Image::GetWidth() and a bunch of other getters be "const"?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+

Why aren't they const?

I believe that's flawed API design. Or am I missing something?

```
UINT GetWidth();
UINT GetHeight();
...
```

vs.

```
UINT GetWidth() const;
UINT GetHeight() const;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say. I'd agree, but perhaps there is something in the implementation that prevents them from being `const`, and that they didn't want to add overhead to hide. Nowdays we have the `mutable` keyword, but I think that is younger than this API.

Or maybe the designers of the API belong to the (sometimes shockingly large, imo) bunch of C++ developers who are hostile towards the `const` keyword, feeling that only makes things harder to use. I'm no Windows historian, so I can't tell you. :)

Comment: Well, some do have const modifier: Image::GetType() const

Answer (score 4):

Flawed API design? C-style C++ headers? From the teams who brought us [CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(VS.60).aspx)? Nah, can't be...

Seriously, though, don't expect [GoTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/)-level C++ usage in any Win32 API, or more than a basic wrapper around the C-style handles. Herb Sutter has been busy with .NET:ing C++ rather than improving Microsoft library design. The [WTL](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5BA5BA4-6E6B-462A-B24C-61115E846F0C&displaylang=en) is as close as I've seen Microsoft come to [modern C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design), and that has led a rather obscure existence.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you are probably right - the variable should be const.

I'm assuming you are talking about the Gdiplus C++ native API. If you look into the implementation of this code and the Gdiplus classes you'll find that most of the code is a basic wrapper around the Gdiplus Flat API functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533969(VS.85).aspx). This might make it either difficult to make the code const-correct... or (as another hinted at) it's Microsoft being typically not-very-modern-C++.

EDIT: Looking at the code for Gdiplus::Image::GetWidth() (in GdiPlusBitmap.h), it would have been easy for MS to implement many of the functions with the const modifier. They've done it with Image::GetType() and the code inside is pretty much identical to Image::GetWidth(), Image::GetHeight().

Comment: Re: EDIT
Exactly. I had constant WTF while reading the GDI+ source code